# OCAML Changing this code from Combination to Permutation

Tags: ocaml, combinations, permutation

this is the code to take an int and a list, to make all the possible combinations of that list given the number of distinct objects. So for example if you plug in the int 2 for the list [1; 2; 3] it gives you [1; 2], [2;3], [1;3]! What I want it to do is give me the permutation instead of combination where the order matters! How do i change this code to do this for me?

```
# let extract k list =
  let rec aux k acc emit = function
  | [] -> acc
  | h :: t ->
    if k = 1 then aux k (emit [h] acc) emit t else
      let new_emit x = emit (h :: x) in
      aux k (aux (k-1) acc new_emit t) emit t
  in
  let emit x acc = x :: acc in
  aux k [] emit list;;

val extract : int -> 'a list -> 'a list list = <fun>
#
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is rather tricky as it depends on redefining the `emit` function to add prefixes to the emitted lists. I think you can write the function a little more straightforwardly.

Be that as it may, one thing to try might be to have `new_emit` (the modified `emit`) add `h` not just as a prefix but at every possible place in the list `x`. I haven't tried this, but it sounds about right.